# R function list with undetermined length as an argument

Tags: r, list, function, ggplot2

I am using the `multiplot` function of this [website](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Multiple_graphs_on_one_page_(ggplot2)/)

This function takes as argument an indefinite number of plots and plot them together. With the code below I can plot for example 4 plots together in 2 columns.

```
library(ggplot2)
n = 4
p = lapply(1:n, function(i) {
    ggplot(data.frame(x = 1:10,y = rep(i,10)), aes(x = x, y = y)) +
    geom_point()
})

multiplot(p[[1]],p[[2]],p[[3]],p[[4]],cols = 2)
```

How can I do if I have an undetermined number of plots `n` ?

I already tried things like

```
multiplot(p,cols = 2)
do.call(multiplot, list(p,cols = 2))
```

but it doesn't give the result that I want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the second option you were also close:

```
do.call(multiplot, c(p, cols = 2))
```

does the job since

```
length(list(p, cols = 2))
# [1] 2
length(c(p, cols = 2))
# [1] 5
```

That is, `list(p, cols = 2)` makes a list of two components: a list `p` and an integer 2, while what you want is to extend `p` by adding `cols = 2`, and we need for that. (Somewhat not immediately obvious perhaps, but the title of `?c` does indeed say *Combine Values into a Vector or **List***.)

Answer (score 2):

maybe  `multiplot(plotlist = p)` !
cheers